# Should I replace my printer's ink damper and printhead?

Tags: printer, inkjet-printer, epson-ecotank

Currently I'm having troubles with my Epson L3150 printer as the damper is not getting ink and the print head looks like it's blocked.

I tried switching placements of the dampers just to try if there's a problem with my damper or my print head. But somehow both have problems.

Do I just buy a cleaning solution to try and unclog it? Or just replace both of them?

Comment: Cleaning often doesn’t last. Look at the cost of replacement parts relative to the cost of replacing the printer.  Can you replace yourself.  These are the determining factors

Comment: I can Replace it by myself. Tho replacing the printer is out of the question cause my boss wants it just be repaired instead of replaced. I even tried Explaining it to him that it's much more expensive than buying a new one. Even with a quotation report.

Comment: Better to replace the mucked up parts. Cleaning doesn’t always work and even if it does it’s never that great a job.

Comment: Shouldn't need a cleaning solution.  I don't know THAT printer head but that doesn't matter.  Most are water based.  I wrote drivers for 180+ inkjet printers.  ALMOST (not always) ink dried up right at the nozzle.  Pour close to boiling water into a stack of folded paper towels.  Set your cartridge nozzle side down (on the towels) and let it sit  (balanced with creative desk items).  After sitting.. add more hot water and sit more.  Then with 2 fresh towels (also hot+wet) .. wipe the head vertical until you see the ink flow.  Usually wrks, sometimes not. Done this 2 many times 2 count.